# Apache virtual hosts not working when using subdomain

Tags: apache, apache2, subdomain, ubuntu-12.04, virtualhost

I am trying to setup a virtual host. I have done this  many times before on different servers with no problem, however, I have never tried it using a subdomain.

For some strange reason when I go to the subdomain: sub.mysite.co.uk I get redirected to the /var/www/mysite directory and not /var/www/other-site

Here is my apache.conf file:

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
 NameVirtualHost *:80

  <ifmodule mod_ssl.c>
      NameVirtualHost *:443
  </ifmodule>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *.mysite.co.uk
DocumentRoot "/var/www/newsletters/"
</VirtualHost>
```

And my sites-enabled file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/newsletters
ServerAlias sub.mysite.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: The same `DocumentRoot` in both `VirtualHost`s is a typo in question?

Comment: the `DocumentRoot` is the same in the first general VirtualHost section (which is triggered) and in the second VirtualHost (which SHOULD be triggered). Is this an error in question or in your configuration?

Comment: None of my virtual host sections seem to be triggered. When I visit: sub.mysite.co.uk I want it to load: /var/www/newsletters. Instead, it loads the default: /var/www

Comment: That's strange. I suspect there is a problem somewhere in the rest of your configuration not posted here. Is the /var/www directory present only as the default `DocumentRoot` or also in some other VirtualHosts? Does `apache2ctl graceful` show some warning?

Comment: Just checked what else was in /etc/apache2/sites-available and it appears that another VirtualHost was previously setup with the same serverName and ServerAlias as my new virtualHost resulting in a conflict. I Cant believe I didn't think to check all the other VHosts files! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your DNS entries? Maybe it's redirecting all subdomains to mysite.co.uk.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in httpd.conf 
`Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf` 
`Listen *:80` 
Write this in custom-vhost.conf located in sites-enabled

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1
    ServerName domain1.me
    ServerAlias www.domain1.me
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it works